# Is the SE iOS app being maintained?

Tags: discussion, ios-app

I noticed the iOS Stack Exchange app is still using the old iOS form factor (pre-iPhone X). Is the app being actively developed?

[image: old iOS screenshot]

If not consider open sourcing it so the community can contribute.

Comment: It’s possible, quite possible.

Comment: Also, AFAIK one of the reasons why they don't open source it because they're using private APIs that is more powerful than the public one

Comment: Please also see [Make the mobile apps open source!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315791/245360).

Comment: Maintained != (features || optimizations). I think it is safe to assume the answer is probably no.