# Not getting notifications

Tags: support, bug, android-app

I'm not getting notifications on a Pixel 3 (9: 1 august 2019 security patch). I'm running version 1.0.95 of the app.

I've tried redownloading the app, clearing storage/cache and disabling and enabling notifications from the app.

Quiet hours are off.

Am I missing anything? Is this a bug?

Comment: The SE mobile apps development is [frozen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300389/388884). Use the website instead.

Comment: Would it be possible for the code to be made open source, and put a repo on github? It would allow users to sideload it on their respective devices

Comment: [Already asked as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315791/make-the-mobile-apps-open-source), with the answer being no (on the linked question).