# Could SE be *actually* convinced to open source chat?

Tags: feature-request, chat, open-source

While *usually* nothing good ever comes out of Twitter—a [recent tweet](https://twitter.com/tinkertim/status/1546900795152547841) by the former Community Manager Tim Post caught my eye

> I wish we'd put more effort into the Bonfire chat we developed at Stack Overflow. They might even be persuaded to open source it, eventually.

We currently have core front end parts of the site like [the Stacks Editor](https://github.com/orgs/StackExchange/projects?query=is%3Aopen&type=beta) and [Stacks](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks) open sourced. I'm not plugged in enough to that side of the company to know the extent of external contributions but... a [recent blog post about the new themes says](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/07/11/stack-exchange-sites-are-getting-prettier-faster-introducing-themes/)

> While we originally wanted to also tackle the chat design, this was cut from our scope due to it not being visible on our designers’ local environments

indicates a desire to fix things (), but not the tooling (). While I realise open sourcing chat's work—it’s probably also work that'll help internal development of chat and general maintainability.

So - *could* Stack Exchange be convinced to put the effort into open sourcing our nice, warm and very beloved bonfire?

Comment: Also, SEDE is open-source

Comment: I think one of the possible issues is if [it contains "internal things", just like the mobile apps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348112/241919)

Comment: When we had the roadmap, I've seen an item about SE starting to look into what can be done to chat, so the question is quite topical. It would be great for integrations including bots and userscripts.

Comment: Some context from the tweet's replies: *"What _is_ bonfire chat? ... SE chat's internal name"*. Presumably something built from the ground up, not on top of an existing chat system by that name. Without it, something like this may turn up: *"[Facebook is shutting down Bonfire, its Houseparty clone for group video chat](https://www.theverge.com/2019/5/3/18528317/facebook-bonfire-shutdown-group-video-chat-houseparty-clone)"* (2019) and *"[Twitter gets instant message chat with Bonfire app](https://www.digitaltrends.com/social-media/twitter-gets-instant-message-chat-with-bonfire-app/)"* (2011).